# How do I append a "target triple" to a binary name in CMake using rustc's output?

Tags: cmake, tauri

I'm using a CMake-generated binary as a [tauri sidecar app](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/sidecar/), which requires that I append a "target triple" to the name of the exe.

Following that page as a guide, I came up with this to query `rustc -Vv` for the triple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(targettriple)
set(BIN myexe)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)

# extract target triple for binary name https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/sidecar/
execute_process(COMMAND rustc -Vv OUTPUT_VARIABLE RUSTC_VV_OUTPUT)
string(REGEX MATCH "host: (.+)" _ "${RUSTC_VV_OUTPUT}")
string(STRIP "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}" RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE)
message(STATUS "RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE = ${RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE}")

# fails:
set_target_properties(${BIN} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${BIN}-${RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE}")

# works:
# set_target_properties(${BIN} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${BIN}-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
```

I get in the output:

```
-- RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

But then when I build I also get:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(31,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\...\build\, C:\Users\...\bin\Debug\myexe-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc [C:\Users\...\build\myexe.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(31,5): error MSB4184: release: 1.66.0 [C:\Users\...\build\myexe.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(31,5): error MSB4184: LLVM version: 15.0.2.exe)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\...\build\myexe.vcxproj]
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. If I hardcode the target triple (as in the last line of the CMakeLists above), it all works fine. What am I doing wrong? Are there mysterious characters in this string that I don't know about?

Comment: are there any [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in the `RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE` value (Ex. doing colouring)?

Comment: The command [exec_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/exec_program.html) is deprecated for a long time. Instead use `execute_process`, which is superior of it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, changed to `execute_process` instead. Same problem so far.

Comment: @user I don't think so, this is the same method recommended by tauri themselves--also, piping the output into `less` without `-R` doesn't show me anything. Any suggestions on how to be certain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your regex is too greedy. When I try it on my machine, it matches the desired contents, and then everything else after that as well:

```
-- RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
release: 1.63.0
LLVM version: 14.0.5
```

Try using `"host: ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"` or something else appropriate for your needs. When I use this, I get:

```
-- RUST_TARGET_TRIPLE = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

You can find the docs for CMake's regex specification here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification

Comment: Oh you’re totally right, my extra lines got lost in the sea of other messages. Silly mistake, thank you!